# Getting this error when I try to execute this program (python file management)

Tags: python, file

[Python file management error could not execute this program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aM1kY.jpg)

Comment: Please post the code along with the error, rather than image attachments.

Answer (score 0):

In this case it's better to use a context manager (with . as .:). And to write the path of your file try to put single back slash instead of two.

```
with open('Users\you\Documents\a_text_file.txt', 'r') as jabber:
    for line in jabber:
        print(line)
```

Comment: Please add comments on how this will solve the OP's question. Code only answers are frowned upon. If you are going to post an answer please make sure it is an answer. Please read [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) to get a better understanding of what an answer is. Please also go through the site [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)